# Inputting x,y,z value from dataset and grouping them into 2 groups (1 or 2)

Tags: python, pandas

I am working on a project with a dataset where columns x,y,z are coordinate. For example x,y,z could equal (1,0,35) or (49,23,5). I want to group them, g1 and g2, for when  25 < x < 49, 12< Y < 23, 15 < Z < 35. Then I want to use input() for x,y,z coordinate and the output will tell me which group the coordinate belongs to.

```
x = pd.DataFrame(dataset, columns= ['x'])
Y = pd.DataFrame(dataset, columns= ['y'])
Z = pd.DataFrame(dataset, columns= ['z'])
g1 = 1
g2 = 2

if 25 < x < 49:
   print(g2)
else:
   print(g1)
if 12< Y < 23:
   print(g2)
else:
   print(g1)
if 15 < Z < 35:
   print(g2)
else:
   print(g1)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Replied to your message.

Answer (score 0):

You must enter the following line: x=1,2,3
The letters will be x or y or z, any number, but separated by commas.
Next, the letter is the name of the column in the date frame, and a list is created from the numbers to transfer it to the dataframe. There should be three numbers. Variable 'how_many', specifies how many digits should fall in the range.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1, 0, 35], 'y': [49, 23, 5], 'z': [51, 2, 10]})


xxx = (input())#Input string must be the following: x=1,2,3
col = xxx[0]#Column name
index = xxx.find("=") + 1#Find the next index after the = sign, this will be the list itself (comma-separated integers)
xxx = xxx[index:].split(',')#Creating a list
xxx = [int(item) for item in xxx]#Converting values to type int


g1 = 1
g2 = 2
how_many = 1 #How many numbers should fall into the range

if col == 'x':
    df['x'] = xxx
    if len(df[(25 < df['x']) & (df['x'] < 49)]['x']) >= how_many:
        print(g2)
    else:
        print(g1)

if col == 'y':
    df['y'] = xxx
    if len(df[(12 < df['y']) & (df['y'] < 23)]['y']) >= how_many:
        print(g2)
    else:
        print(g1)

if col == 'z':
    df['z'] = xxx
    if len(df[(15 < df['z']) & (df['z'] < 35)]['z']) >= how_many:
        print(g2)
    else:
        print(g1)
```